# Design bug in badge page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges

The date and post title overlap on the [tumbleweed badge page](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/21/tumbleweed), as well as other post-related [badge pages](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/45?page=7). As Monica noted in the comments, there also seems to be a vertical offset between the two.

[image: Screenshot from the Tumbleweed badge page, showing two rows in which the date - "may 10 '11 at 18:48" - overlaps with the question title immediately to its right, and one in which the date - "mar 10 at 18:42" doesn't.]

Comment: I see it as well.

Comment: And is that vertical offset supposed to be there?  (The timestamps are a little higher than the titles.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yeah, I noticed that too....

Comment: With the new badge-page design, this is no longer an issue, so I'm tagging this question [meta-tag:status-completed].