# Badly aligned rows in HTML table

Tags: bug, design, badges, cleanup-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Design bug in badge page](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1150/design-bug-in-badge-page)

I looked at the list of users that got [cleanup](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/4/cleanup) badge, and it seems to me that the date and the link to question and user are not aligned well in the table. Scroll to the end of the page to see this.

I checked this in Chrome and in FF.

Comment: Which version of Firefox?  I'm not seeing it in 14.0.1 on a Mac (10.6).

Comment: @MonicaCellio Mine is FF 14.0.1 on Ubuntu

Comment: Could you add a screenshot?  Thanks.

Comment: Dupe? http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1150/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Ok, then I'm going to close this one.

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks.